# Remove embedded frame in Google Sheets

Tags: html, css, google-sheets

How Can I Remove this Frame and use my own one . [Google Sheet embedded frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it4Hw.png)

Comment: Are you talking about the frame border that goes around it? Or are you talking about that little tab at the bottom?

Comment: frame border that goes around it

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the information that I see, you want to change the `frameborder`. This can be done using CSS and HTML, and is actually pretty easy.

First, you want to change your `iframe` to have the attribute `frameborder="0"` so you don't cause overlapping frame borders. Here is an example:

```html
<iframe src="http://example.com" frameborder=0></iframe>
```

Next, create a CSS class in your stylesheet to resemble the border.

```css
.frame1 {}
```

In this case, I will be using `.frame1`. Apply the class to the `iframe`, then  add a `border` CSS attribute to your class. The full border code should look something like this:

```css
.frame1 {
    border: 4px #ff2d00 solid;
}
```

You can play around with the width, color, and line type to match your specific use case. In the end, your full code should look something like this:

```css
.frame1 {
  border: 4px #ff2d00 solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <iframe src="http://example.com" frameborder=0 class="frame1" height="500px" width="500px"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

If you would like to interact with the code, or fork it, you can go to [this codepen project I made](https://codepen.io/TheCrafters001/pen/PoWNvGL).

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately . I already tried it before asking the question.
The problem is that I don't Know how google-sheets made it so I can't remove it.